# Playing file while waiting to process gather action

Tags: twilio

I'm using Twilio's TwiML `<Gather>` verb to collect input from the user and use the action verb to process the request. The process takes some time so I would like to play a file while the request is processed. Right now there is a 2-3 sec silence that is not great for the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you need to something while your input is processed, then you should respond to the `<Gather>` action immediately with something like a [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play). Then, when you are finished processing the response, you need to [modify the live call and redirect it using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls) to the next TwiML response.

Comment: Thanks, works great!. Is there a way to avoid interrupting the <play> action? Ideally I would like to be able to get the TwilioML file to be 'appended' to the play action in such a way that the new TwilioML actions are processed as soon as the Play action is completed.

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. One way I'd try is to have a `<Redirect>` after the `<Play>` that takes the call to another endpoint in your application. With that endpoint you can check to see if the input is successfully processed and if so continue the call. Otherwise you could redirect back to the `<Play>` to give the process more time. What do you think?